# Unable to write to a file with group permissions

Tags: linux, ubuntu

We are getting the error "permission denied" when trying to write to a file that is owned by a service user and a shared group. In particular that is www-data:www-data and the user trying to write to it is in the group www-data.

There is no acl on none of the parent folders and the permissions to the file and folders are correct.

Here some details:

```
$ sudo -u deploy id -Gn
www-data
$ ls -lah /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 17 root     root     4.0K Jul 11 11:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root     root     4.0K Jul  8 10:08 ..
...
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data    0 Jul 11 10:50 test
...
$ echo 'hello world' | sudo -u deploy tee -a /tmp/test
tee: /tmp/test: Permission denied
hello world
```

we tried that on different folders and made sure there is no acl on any of the folders or parents or files...

Comment: explanation of /tmp permissions https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/71622/64699

Comment: should I add that to my description why it is 1777 and not 0777?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is not described in the link stark posted in the comment. And also not in any other page I found until I found an answer here on stackoverflow that clarified it.

2018 two new filesystem configurations got added to sysctl that should prevent regular files and fifos from beeing opened with the O_CREAT flag (as append mode is doing) in directories with the sticky bit set unless the user is the owner of the file. This commit added the settings: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=30aba6656f61ed44cba445a3c0d38b296fa9e8f5

To change that behaviour you have to set `fs.protected_regular` to 0:

```
sudo sysctl fs.protected_regular=0
```

Or to persist the change add `fs.protected_regular=0` to your `sysctl.conf`.

side node: since O_CREAT is not deleting or renaming the file I'm wondered why it is connected to the sticky bit. It really is possible to create a file in directories with the stick bit set.